# Setting up hostapd with a iwlwifi device to run a hotspot

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, networkmanager, hostapd

I am trying to configure my opensuse 13.1 system to function as a hotspot (on my dell xps13 computer).

So I tried setting up hostapd as explained [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ctS5.png), but I get an error:

```
hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Failed to set interface wlp1s0 into AP mode
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
```

My hostapd.conf file:

```
#interface=wlan0
interface=wlp1s0
driver=nl80211
bridge=br0

logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2

dump_file=/run/hostapd.dump
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
hw_mode=g
channel=3
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
rts_threshold=2347
fragm_threshold=2346
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0


wmm_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
# Note: for IEEE 802.11b mode: cWmin=5 cWmax=10
#
# Normal priority / AC_BE = best effort
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
# Note: for IEEE 802.11b mode: cWmin=5 cWmax=7
#
# High priority / AC_VI = video
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
# Note: for IEEE 802.11b mode: cWmin=4 cWmax=5 txop_limit=188
#
# Highest priority / AC_VO = voice
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0
# Note: for IEEE 802.11b mode: cWmin=3 cWmax=4 burst=102


# EAPOL-Key index workaround (set bit7) for WinXP Supplicant (needed only if
# only broadcast keys are used)
eapol_key_index_workaround=0
# authentication server.
eap_server=0

# The own IP address of the access point (used as NAS-IP-Address)
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
```

The problem might be with the driver. Perhaps I should indicate another one, since:

```
>> lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i "network"
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Some more netcard info:

```
 >>hwinfo --netcard | grep -Ei "model|driver" 
  Model: "Intel WLAN controller"
  Driver: "iwlwifi"
  Driver Modules: "iwlwifi"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: iwlwifi is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe iwlwifi"
  Model: "ASIX Electronics AX88x72A"
  Driver: "asix"
  Driver Modules: "asix"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: asix is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe asix"

 >>modinfo iwlwifi | grep 'depend'
depends:        cfg80211
```

--update: I checked that my card supports AP like this:

```
>>iw dev
phy#0
        Interface wlp1s0
                ifindex 2
                wdev 0x1
                addr c8:f7:33:da:ac:d7
                type managed



>>iw phy#0 info
Wiphy phy0
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x1072                                                                                               
                        HT20/HT40                                                                                                  
                        Static SM Power Save
                        RX Greenfield
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        No RX STBC
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15, 32
                Frequencies:
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (15.0 dBm)
                        * 2467 MHz [12] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 2472 MHz [13] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 1.0 Mbps
                        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
        Band 2:
                Capabilities: 0x1072
                        HT20/HT40
                        Static SM Power Save
                        RX Greenfield
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        No RX STBC
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15, 32
                Frequencies:
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS)
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
        max # scan SSIDs: 20
        max scan IEs length: 195 bytes
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
        Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
        software interface modes (can always be added):
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1,
                   total <= 2, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
                 * #{ managed } <= 2,
                   total <= 2, #channels <= 1
        Supported commands:
                 * new_interface
                 * set_interface
                 * new_key
                 * start_ap
                 * new_station
                 * new_mpath
                 * set_mesh_config
                 * set_bss
                 * authenticate
                 * associate
                 * deauthenticate
                 * disassociate
                 * join_ibss
                 * join_mesh
                 * remain_on_channel
                 * set_tx_bitrate_mask
                 * frame
                 * frame_wait_cancel
                 * set_wiphy_netns
                 * set_channel
                 * set_wds_peer
                 * probe_client
                 * set_noack_map
                 * register_beacons
                 * Unknown command (89)
                 * Unknown command (92)
                 * connect
                 * disconnect
        Supported TX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        Supported RX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * managed: 0x40 0xd0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
        Device supports RSN-IBSS.
        WoWLAN support:
                 * wake up on disconnect
                 * wake up on magic packet
                 * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes
                 * can do GTK rekeying
                 * wake up on GTK rekey failure
                 * wake up on EAP identity request
                 * wake up on rfkill release
        HT Capability overrides:
                 * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
                 * maximum A-MSDU length
                 * supported channel width
                 * short GI for 40 MHz
                 * max A-MPDU length exponent
                 * min MPDU start spacing
        Device supports TX status socket option.
        Device supports HT-IBSS.
```

Thanks for any insight and suggestions. I really need to set up a wireless hotspot.

--update

I have executed the following commands error free:

```
   nmcli nm wifi off
    rfkill unblock wlan

    ip link set dev wlp1s0 up
    ip address add 192.168.5.1/24 dev wlp1s0

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.5.0/24 -o enp0s20u2 -j MASQUERADE
    sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 1> /dev/null

    systemctl start hostapd.service
    systemctl start dnsmasq.service
```

My /etc/hostapd is:

```
interface=wlp1s0
driver=nl80211
# bridge=br0
channel=3
hw_mode=g
auth_algs=1
ssid=test
```

My phone sees the test network. But keeps saying "Obtaining IP address...."

Comment: Did you start a DHCP server? DNSMasq doesn't enable its DHCP component by default. Try editing your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file to enable DHCP and restarting the service, or give your phone a static IP address.

Comment: Quote from the section "features " from http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi : "AP mode (experimental; only on some devices/firmware versions)". Make sure your card actually supports it via `iw list | grep AP`.

Answer (score 2):

you specified the wrong driver on your hostapd conf file, use iwlwifi (intel) instead of nl80211 (atheros)
when you follow a guide you have to read and change anything necesary for your own needs.

Comment: nl80211 is not an atheros specific module, but the module for the framework all modern wifi drivers (including iwlwifi) use. https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/nl80211 You can see above "depends: cfg80211".

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this guide exactly you should find success:

> http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-setting-wireless-access-point/

I have used the guide on Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Be careful when you cut and paste into a `ssh` client or PuTTY terminal. I had to delete extra spaces that were inserted and it brought up errors, sorted that out and all was well.

Currently trying to extend this guide with scripts to change interfaces, when virtual machine security appliance fails - it will start the WiFi network up with a bridge to the modem to bypass the security appliance.

Comment: The text on your link contains no word 'iwlwifi'. That is for another driver.